# How to get the current loaction [sic] system in rails website

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, postgresql

When a user clicks the 'Punch In' button, I want to get the location where the user clicked the button.

Comment: There is a lot of information in the internet. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "current location"? The mouse x/y position on the screen when clicking? Or the user's location guessed by the computer's public IP address? If the latter are you aware that guessing the location from the public IP is not very reliable - mine, for example, is constantly 250km off my current location and in another state.

Comment: My requirement is to know  current location of the user from where he is mark his attendance by click on 'Punch   In' button.so,i want to know,how i can implement this in rails website?

Comment: @RituRajora I'm still not sure what kind of "location" you mean. Could you give an example, please?

Comment: I mean when user click on location button it should reflect location of the place for eg: if i am at D block sector 132 noida then after clicking on location it should reflect the exact location where i am.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Geocoder** gem to achieve this.

```
result = request.location
```

For more information check here https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder.

Happy Coding.